# regex - URL extension redirect help

Tags: regex, redirect

I have a couple of domain extensions that I'd like to redirect to specific pages.
Like example.de has to redirect to example.de/de/ and example.fr to example.fr/fr/.

How can I achieve this? I'm new to regex.

Comment: Where is this redirection to be done?  In server-side code (what language?), client-side (javascript?) or web server config?

Answer (score 0):

You will edit your .htacess file and put something like to  :

```
RedirectMatch permanent example\.de/$ http://example.de/de
RedirectMatch permanent example\.fr/$ http://example.fr/fr
....
```

Comment: Try adding two more lines : `RedirectMatch permanent example\.de$ http://example.de/de
RedirectMatch permanent example\.fr$ http://example.fr/fr` ??